# import 500mb csv file into database using MySQL terminal

Tags: mysql, shell, csv, import, terminal

I am trying to import a csv file into mysql database using mysql terminal, nothing seems to work I either get error 1064 or nothing happens after I hit enter.

So far I have tried:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname -e "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/file.csv'     INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (field1, field2, field3)";
```

which does nothing if I hit enter without the ; at the end, and with the ; I get error 1064 incorrect syntax.

I have also tried:

```
mysql -u username -p password -h localhost dbname

use dbname

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/file.csv' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' (field1, field2, field3);
```

is this correct?

---

I am using the statements below, and this is the error message I am receiving:

```
mysql->mysql -u username -ppassword

->use database

->LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/datafeed.csv'
->INTO TABLE table_name
->FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
->LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
->(field1, field2, field3);

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u username -ppassword use database LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/datafe' at line 1
```

Comment: Many people who troubleshoot data loading problems use tiny subsets of their files for testing. Once the tiny subset loads correctly, they move on to loading the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the LOAD DATA statement itself looks correct...

it looks suitable if the MySQL server is installed on a Windows machine, and the specified file exists and is readable on the server. (There's no `LOCAL` keyword before `INFILE`, so that's saying that the file is on the server machine, not the client machine.)

The first thing you show you have tried, I think the **double quote character** within the `LOAD DATA` statement is actually terminating the string, that is, it's being "matched" to the double quote before the `LOAD DATA`.

---

The fact you are reporting that you are getting a 1064 error makes it appear you are able to connect to the MySQL server.

The form I use for running the mysql command line client on the server machine:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword database
```

(Note that there's no space between -p and the password.)

I'm a little confused, whether the MySQL server is actually running on a Windows machine, and if you're running in a CMD.EXE window...  there's not enough information provided for me to determine that.

Comment: Its a Windows server, im opening the mysql.exe from the bin directory and running the commands from the terminal.

Comment: Just enter the `LOAD DATA` statement at the `mysql>` prompt.

Comment: Just using the load data statement shows error 'no database selected' , so I connect to the database and then run the LOAD DATA statement and nothing happens

Comment: You say "nothing happens", maybe the statement is running. From another database session, what does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show? You might want to setup a test with a much smaller amount of data, a .csv file containing only a couple of lines.

Comment: I am now using a much smaller file, after I hit enter I get no response in the terminal, it just goes to the next line, SHOW PROCESSLIST does the same

Comment: You say it "goes to the next line", do you mean you hit the enter key, and mysql displays a continuation **->** prompt, or that mysql displays a new **mysql>** prompt, or mysql client exits and Windows displays a `C:\Windows\Program Files>` prompt? (The description of the behavior you observe is vague and imprecise.) The MySQL command line client accepts multiple lines for a statement; it doesn't submit the statement to the database until you enter **`\g`** or a semicolon (`;`) character. This is described in the [**Reference Manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html)

Comment: I have updated the question with the exact error message